# How to pass bundle to the fragments in android

Tags: android-fragments, nullpointerexception, bundle

I am developing application consists of navigation drawer with swipe tabs 
Here i need to pass the bundle to the navigation drawer from my home activity at the time of receiving bundle i am getting `nullpointerexception` can any one help me 
This is my Home activity:

```
package android.lotus.com.androidmis;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.lotus.mis.modle.MyAppApplication;
import com.lotus.mis.modle.UserDetails;

public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    NavigationView mNavigationView;
    FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    Toolbar toolbar;
    public static String UserName, userID, FlagList, User_code, Mail_id,
            user_reporting_level;
    UserDetails ObjUserDetails;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_home);

        /**Getting bundle from the LotusLogin screen**/
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        UserName = bundle.getString("key_username");
        ObjUserDetails = (UserDetails) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("UserDetails");
        /**getting user details from the UserDetails modle**/
        userID = ObjUserDetails.getUserID();
        User_code = ObjUserDetails.getEmpCode();
        Mail_id = ObjUserDetails.getEmail();
        user_reporting_level = ObjUserDetails.getPOSITION();


        /**Setting user details as global user details*/
        MyAppApplication mApp = new MyAppApplication();
        mApp.setmGlobal_UserID(userID);
        mApp.setMGlobal_EmpID(User_code);
        mApp.setMGlobal_mailID(Mail_id);
//setting bundle to travels fragment
        Bundle travels_bundle = new Bundle();
        travels_bundle.putString("key_username", UserName);
        travels_bundle.putString("key_userid", userID);
        Travels travels_fragment = new Travels();
        travels_fragment.setArguments(travels_bundle);
        if (user_reporting_level.equalsIgnoreCase("-")) {
            mApp.setmGlobal_reporting_level("");
        } else {
            mApp.setmGlobal_reporting_level(user_reporting_level);
        }
        FlagList = "3";


        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.shitstuff);

        mFragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mFragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        mFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Travels()).commit();
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();


               /* if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sent) {
                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new SentFragment()).commit();

                }
*/
                if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_travels) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Travels()).commit();
                    /** Passing bundle to the travels fragment*/
                    Bundle travels_bundle = new Bundle();
                    travels_bundle.putString("key_username", UserName);
                    travels_bundle.putString("key_userid", userID);
                    Travels travels_fragment = new Travels();
                    travels_fragment.setArguments(travels_bundle);


                } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sales) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Sales()).commit();
                } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_sales_reports) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new SalesReports()).commit();
                } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_voucher) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Voucher()).commit();
                } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_daylog) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Daylog()).commit();
                } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_leaves) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Leaves()).commit();
                } else if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_complaints) {
                    FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, new Complaints()).commit();

                }


                return false;
            }

        });

        ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.app_name,
                R.string.app_name);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        mDrawerToggle.syncState();


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my home activity bundle i am passing

```
 Bundle travels_bundle = new Bundle();
        travels_bundle.putString("key_username", UserName);
        travels_bundle.putString("key_userid", userID);
        Travels travels_fragment = new Travels();
        travels_fragment.setArguments(travels_bundle);
```

This is my navigation drawer fragment:

```
package android.lotus.com.androidmis;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.subtabs.travels.Cancelled;
import com.subtabs.travels.Today;
import com.subtabs.travels.Upcoming;
import com.subtabs.travels.History;


public class Travels extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    public static TabLayout tabLayout;
    public static ViewPager viewPager;
    public static int int_items = 4 ;
    public String UserName,UserID;


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        /**
         *Inflate tab_layout and setup Views.
         */
        View x =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_layout,container,false);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) x.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) x.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);

        /**Getting bundle from Home screen of Travels module*/
        Bundle travels_bundle = this.getArguments();     //Error occuring place
        UserName = travels_bundle.getString("key_username");
        UserID = travels_bundle.getString("key_userid");
        /**
         *Set an Apater for the View Pager
         */
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));

        /**
         * Now , this is a workaround ,
         * The setupWithViewPager dose't works without the runnable .
         * Maybe a Support Library Bug .
         */

        tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            }
        });

        return x;

    }

    class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        /**
         * Return fragment with respect to Position .
         */

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position)
        {
            switch (position){
                case 0 :
                    /**Sending bundle to the upcoming fragment of Travels module*/
                    Bundle upcoming_bundle = new Bundle();
                    upcoming_bundle.putString("key_username",UserName);
                    upcoming_bundle.putString("key_userid", UserID);
                    upcoming_bundle.putString("key_TravelFlag","1");
                    Upcoming upcoming_fragment = new Upcoming();
                    upcoming_fragment.setArguments(upcoming_bundle);
                    return new Upcoming();

                case 1 : return new History();
                case 2 : return new Today();
                case 3 : return new Cancelled();

            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {

            return int_items;

        }

        /**
         * This method returns the title of the tab according to the position.
         */

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Upcoming";
                case 1:
                    return "History";
                case 2:
                    return "Today";
                case 3:
                    return "Cancelled";

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

From this navigation drawer fragment i am having the 4 swipe tabs and pass the which was received in above bundle.

Answer (score 0):

Please return the Fragment object.

```
  /**Sending bundle to the upcoming fragment of Travels module*/ 
                    Bundle upcoming_bundle = new Bundle();
                    upcoming_bundle.putString("key_username",UserName);
                    upcoming_bundle.putString("key_userid", UserID);
                    upcoming_bundle.putString("key_TravelFlag","1");
                    Upcoming upcoming_fragment = new Upcoming();
                    upcoming_fragment.setArguments(upcoming_bundle);
                    return upcoming_fragment; ////// Changed Here
```

And also add this code -

```
 /**Getting bundle from Home screen of Travels module*/ 
        Bundle travels_bundle = this.getArguments();     //Error occuring place
        UserName = travels_bundle.getString("key_username");
        UserID = travels_bundle.getString("key_userid");
```

After setting the adapter.

**EDIT**

```
if (menuItem.getItemId() == R.id.nav_item_travels) {

       /** Passing bundle to the travels fragment*/
                                Bundle travels_bundle = new Bundle();
                                travels_bundle.putString("key_username", UserName);
                                travels_bundle.putString("key_userid", userID);
                                Travels travels_fragment = new Travels();
                                travels_fragment.setArguments(travels_bundle);
              FragmentTransaction xfragmentTransaction = mFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                                xfragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.containerView, travels_fragment).commit();
}
```

Comment: At the starting of the Travels Fragment i am getting `nullpointer exception` at the bundle @Shoeb Siddique

Comment: From where you are putting the data in the bundle?

Comment: From my home activity.I posted home activity too.please check it @Shoeb Siddique

Comment: Please see my edits, you have to changed the code in Home activity while replacing Fragment. ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102560/discussion-between-shoeb-siddique-and-lakshman).

Comment: But at the starting of my home activity i am putting data in bundle  and  passing that data is there any error with that @ Shoeb Siddique

Comment: Not working dude still error occurring at travels fragment @Shoeb Siddique